# What really is DAC - Dedicated Administrator Connection in SqlServer 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

What really is DAC? When is DAC to be used?

Comment: +1 to ajdams for the link but I would add - be very careful when using the DAC, do not make it your default way of connecting the server and do not try updating values in system tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should answer both those questions =):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068.aspx